# Remove all lines after a specific line in Python

Tags: python, regex

How would I remove all lines in a text file after a specific line?

For example, I want to change the file:

This is important line one.
This is important line two.
Here begins the throw away lines.
Here is throw away line one.
And this is throw away line two.

To this:

This is important line one.
This is important line two.

I think I would want to regex match r'Here begins the (.|\n)*' to match everything in the file after 'Here begins the', but then I'm lost.

I tried this but it's not working:

```
import re  
with open ("file1.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:  
    lines = f.readlines()

found_line = re.search(r'^Here begins the(.|\n)*',lines)  
lines = lines[:found_line.start()]  
with open ("file1.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:  
    f.writelines(lines)
```

Thank you.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking how to write the regex expression (yours seems correct), apply your regex, or read/write the file? The question isn't very clear, but it would be clearer if you could edit it to include the relevant code that you have so far.

Comment: I was looking for how to apply the regex. Sorry about that. I edited the question.

Comment: Great! You've already got some great answers so I won't answer myself, but just one other nitpick for next time - when you say "it's not working", please be more specific about what's "not working". As in, "I tried this code and it gives me this error", or "I tried this code and it does this instead of this", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file, apply the regex you mentioned with [re.sub()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) and write to the file like this:

```
import re
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
    
subbed_data = re.sub(r'Here begins the throw away lines.(.|\n)*', "", data)

with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(subbed_data)
```

Output:

```
This is important line one.
This is important line two.
```

Comment: That worked Ash. Thanks. When I had a '^' at the start of the regex to mark it as the beginning of the line, it did not work. I have no idea why that would cause it not to work.

Answer (score 1):

You could read the file line by line, and break the loop when the line matches your regex.

```
import re

lines = []
with open ("file1.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:  
    for line in f:
        if re.search(r'^Here begins the(.|\n)*', line):
            break
        lines.append(line)

with open ("file1.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:  
    f.writelines(lines)
```

By the way, you could replace `re.search(r'^Here begins the(.|\n)*', line)` with `line.startswith("Here begins the")` and remove the `re` library since you are just checking the beginning ouf the string to see if the line matches your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `^` with multiple lines, you have to use `re.MULTILINE` or `re.M` for short.

This pattern `(.|\n)*` is a very inefficient construction. What you can do instead is use `.*` and use the `re.S` flag to have to dot match a newline.

Then use `re.sub` to replace the whole match with an empty string.

```
import re

with open("file.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as inp:
    allLines = inp.read()

    with open("file.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as outp:
        outp.writelines(re.sub(r'^Here begins the.*', "", allLines, 0, re.M | re.S))
```

Or the pattern with inline modifiers:

```
outp.writelines(re.sub(r'(?ms)^Here begins the.*', "", allLines))
```